# Python, Odoo v10

Tags: odoo

I got the following error while I was checking for the duplicate employee in loan module
    "InternalError": current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
Following is my code:

```
 @api.multi 
def _check_duplicate_employee(self):
    employee_loan_ids=self.search([('state','=',"approved"),('id','!=','ids')])
    loan_employee=[]
    for emp_ids in self(employee_loan_ids):
        loan_employee.append(emp_ids.employee_id.id) 
    if self.state == "approved" and self.employee_id.id in loan_employee:
        return False

    return True
_constraints = [
    (_check_duplicate_employee, 'One of the loan of this employee is already approved ', ['employee_id']),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed:

employee_loan_ids is recordset already so you don't need to use self(employee_loan_ids)

```
for emp_ids in employee_loan_ids:
```

And if `self.state` is translated, you need to translate "approved" too.